# Jensen Inequality.

Tags: probability, jensen-inequality

Sorry, I haven't touched math for some time. My math skill is very rusty. $X$ is a random variable. Can I ask when is the following equation true (or is it always true?). "Condition" here I am referring the things such as convexity, idk, do we need anything such as convexity in the random variable in order to make things true?

$$|EX| \leq E|X|$$

---

If this is true, how do I know the gap between the two? $$\text{gap}=E|X| - |EX|$$

Comment: It's always true (as you mention, it's Jensen inequality).

Comment: Gap depends on the properties of $X$. If $X$ is discrete variable that becomes $x_i$ with probability $p_i$, then $E|X|=\sum_i p_i |x_i|$, $|EX|=|\sum_i p_i x_i|$, ${\rm gap} = (\sum_i p_i |x_i|)-|\sum_i p_i x_i|$

Comment: Jense holds with equality iff the function is a.s. affine. The function f(x)=|x| is a.s. affine, if $x \ge 0$ a.s. or $x \le 0$ a.s.